# mysql php create extra colulmn in rs using as

Tags: php, mysql, recordset

I have a question to which I have been unable to find the answer.

I can create an extra column in a PHP recordset by using an existing column and duplicating it:

```
SELECT 
    id_tst, 
    name_tst, 
    age_tst, 
    price_tst, 
    price_tst AS newprice_tst 
FROM test_tst
```

From what I can work out the `AS` will only duplicate an existing colulmn or rename a column rs.

I want to add two extra columns to a table, *but with no values*.

I know a lot of people will say whats the point in that; it's pointless to have 2 columns with no data.

The reason is I am doing a price updating module for a CMS system, where the user can download a `.csv` file containing prices, modify the prices in a spreadsheet then re-upload the CSV to update he prices.
the two extra columns would be to hold the new prices keeping the old so a roll back from the CSV file could be performed if nessecary.

I could just get the client to add the two new colulmns into the spreadsheet, but would prefer to have the exported CSV with the columns already in place.

Is it possible to create blank columns when creaing an rs?

Comment: The `AS` keyword doesn't create a new column, but aliases another one, or something else. When you say `i want to add two extra columns to a table BUT WITH NO VALUES`, is this in the actual structure or just on the output?

Comment: Can you no just do for example: SELECT '' AS Empty1,'' AS Empty2,column1,column2 FROM table ('' are 2 single quotes)

Comment: just on the output, its just so they get added to the generated csv file, csv generator file loops through the rs i dont hink theres anyway of generaing the extra columns from that

Comment: You can just do SELECT NULL as 'NullColumn' FROM test_tst and that will add a null column (named NullColumn) to your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create empty "dummy" columns by aliasing a blank string:

```
SELECT '' AS emptyColumn, column1, column2 FROM table
```

This will produce another column in your query with all blank values.